# Can an URL fragment point to a HTML element that has no id?

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, uri, uri-fragment

I'd like to provide a link to an external page (not under my control) that has a specific part where I want it to point to (it's a license page with an appendix, and I want the link to go directly to the appendix).

I would normally do this with a `#` in the URL, like this:
`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Examples`

This makes the page scroll to already start on the HTML element with `id="Examples"`.
The problem is when the HTML page doesn't put an `id` on the elements.

Is there any other way to make the URL point to the relevant section? Do URL fragments accept only ids or can I use other CSS selectors somehow?

Comment: Can you give me the html of your section ?

Comment: Oh, I looked on the page today, and found an id now (I think it wasn't there before when I looked months ago). So my problem is solved, but the question remains: is it possible to reference an HTML element in the URL without being by id?

Comment: [How to create permalinks on particular position for web pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29409402/1591669)

Comment: So I assume that without an id it's not possible then. I wonder if the behavior of "browsers scrolling to show the element identified in a URL fragment" is just a convention that browsers happen to follow or if it's expected behavior (defined in a spec or something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer simply is: you cannot.

An `id` attribute on elements is required (barring very specific JavaScript features on your target page, and barring extensions that inject stuff after the fact) to link to a specific element on the page.

The scrolling behavior is defined in [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#find-a-potential-indicated-element), under section "Scrolling to a fragment":

> To **find a potential indicated element** given a `Document` *document* and a string *fragment*, run these steps:
>
> 1. If there is an element in the document tree whose root is *document* and that has an ID equal to *fragment*, then return the first such element in tree order.
> 2. If there is an `a` element in the document tree whose root is document that has a `name` attribute whose value is equal to *fragment*, then return the first such element in tree order.
> 3. Return null.

Notes:

- The `name` attribute for `a` is not valid in current HTML5 anymore.
- The empty `#` fragment (as well as the `#top` fragment, if no `top` id is defined on the page) can be used to scroll to the top of the page.