# How can i link button in html to another class/div

Tags: html, button, hyperlink, footer

I have a 1 page website, how can I link my button if I click it that it goes down to my footer id of my footer is `Footersite`

My code:

```
<div class="openbutton">
    <a href="Footersite">
       <p style="color: white; font-size: 17px;">Contact us</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

But it doesnt go down. How can i fix this?

Comment: Please also show code for the footer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link to an element within the current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386212/link-to-an-element-within-the-current-page)

Comment: try `<a href="#Footersize">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even Though you can achieve this with an anchor tag that is not the only way. With `button` element you can achieve this

**HTML Button**

```css
div {
  margin-top: 800px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="window.location.href='#abc'">Button</button>
<div id="abc"></div>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8erLxo4h/1/)**

If you want an anchor element then

**Anchor tag**

```css
div {
  margin-top: 800px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<a href="#abc">Link</a>
<div id="abc"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use anchor link to achieve this:

```html
<div class="openbutton">

  <a href="#Footersite">
    <p style="color: white;font-size: 17px;">
      Contact us
    </p>
  </a>

</div>

<a name="Footersite"></a>
<div style="margin:1000px 0;">
  Footersite
</div>
```

Comment: And what if it is a class ?

Comment: You need Javascript to do with classname