# How to link a button in one component to a div in anotherr component in reactjs app?

Tags: html, reactjs

I am building a reactjs app which has a few components in it
(a navbar, a hero section,a form, and footer)
i want that when clicked on a button in navbar it scrolls down to form i.e another component,
I tried using react-router but it only renders that form and need it to scroll down to form keeping other components in place.
How can i achieve this?
[basically this but in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945463/how-can-i-link-button-in-html-to-another-class-div?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to achieve this by using vanilla Javascript like this:

```js
<button
  onclick="document.getElementById('idOfForm').scrollIntoView()">
</button>
```

Comment: I tried out this but react does not allow to directly access Dom elements :(